# Detect element that has the same attribute value as another element

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

I have some content that is loaded from a XML file with XMLHttpRequest:

```
<div uid="29710" >
content....
</div>
<div uid="19291" >
content....
</div>
<div uid="099181" >
content....
</div>
```

The code used to get the content:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","notes.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("noteboard");
var newHTML = "";
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
   newHTML += "<div><div uid='"+ x[i].getAttribute('uid')+"'>"
            + x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "<br>"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
           +"</div></div>";
}
document.querySelector('#panel').innerHTML += newHTML;
```

The content is updated every 3 seconds, but the problem starts when the old content is repeated and piled up, as well as the new content. Also, the UID attribute value is loaded from the same XML file as the content - so all the new repeated content has the same UID as the old repeated content.

If I am not clear enough, this is the sort of thing that is happening:

```
<div uid="19291">Old Content</div>
<div uid="77191">New Content</div>
<div uid="19291">Old Content</div>
<div uid="19291">Old Content</div>
<div uid="21503">New Content</div>
```

So how would you remove all the divs that have the same UID value as each other, *except* for the original one ?

Comment: how are you adding it in the first place ? (*show code*)

Comment: Okay, the answer was edited.

Comment: ok, added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `uid` you are adding already exists in the page before adding it.

```js
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","notes.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("noteboard");
var newHTML = "";
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 

  // check if the UID exists in the page and only add it if it does not
  var uid = x[i].getAttribute('uid');
  if ( !document.querySelector('#panel *[uid="'+ uid +'"]') ){

    newHTML += "<div><div uid='"+ x[i].getAttribute('uid')+"'>"
            + x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "<br>"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "</div></div>";
  }
}

document.querySelector('#panel').innerHTML += newHTML;
```

Comment: Great! Even better than removing the duplicate element after it was added.

Answer (score 1):

One option (using "vanilla javascript", no jQuery), if you are sure that the correct element is first in the DOM, is to use `document.querySelectorAll` to loop through the elements, [removing each of](https://jsfiddle.net/fbh21q0n/) them except the first one. For instance, if you had a `<div>` with an ID of `panel` and you wanted to remove divs with a duplicate UID (using `11111` as an example) from inside of this container:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[uid="11111"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(el, idx) { 
    if(idx > 0) { 
        document.getElementById('panel').removeChild(el);    
    }
});
```

`Array.prototype` is used because `document.querySelectorAll` returns an array-like [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), not an actual Array.

(Update following OP's update: this would go after the data has been retrieved from the XML file.)

Answer (score 1):

You can see if your document already has a `div` with that uid.

```
var div = document.querySelector('div[uid=' + items[i].getAttribute('uid') + ']');
```

The code above will search the document any div that has an attribute `uid` with the same value.

So, your final code will be something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  var items = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("noteboard");

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var div = document.querySelector('div[uid=' + items[i].getAttribute('uid') + ']');
    var newHTML = '';
    if (!div) { // it doesn't exist yet
      newHTML += "<div><div uid='"+ x[i].getAttribute('uid')+"'>"
            + x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            + "<br>"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("message")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
           +"</div></div>";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML += newHTML;
});

xhr.open("GET", "notes.xml", false);
xhr.send();
```